# bash script send email recipient from reading. txt file

Tags: bash, email, zip, send

I made a bash script that watches a folder and when you copy a file, it is automatically sent to a specific address.

Suppose now that the files are named as follows:

red.zip
green.zip

how do I send the file to the addresses:

```
red.zip to red@gmail.com
green.zip to green@gmail.com
```

or better yet you can do by reading a txt file where email addresses are:
example;

rosso.zip > to read file red.txt with inside red@gmail.com red1@gmail.com red2@gmail.com

Thank you very much

Comment: I assume your native language is Italian which made you write `rosso.zip` instead of `red.zip`?

Comment: How would you like the attachment to be made? The built-in `mail` on Unix/Linux systems is usually rather rudimentary. Can you install additional standard packages?

Comment: To be more specific: can you install the strandard package `mutt`?

Comment: @MarcusRickert YES I'm Italian :)

Comment: @MarcusRickert I did a little test and end with the appropriate changes to your advice seems to be going all right. Eventually I will use only POSTFIX (SMTP server only) MUTT I do not need.
How can I create a file where I reporlog warns of mail not sent?

Comment: @MarcusRickert sorry, but i can mention you only here (in this post.I do not know why). 
i have another simple question.
Can i read all list recipient putt in only file .txt or .xls instead of a file for each .zip?

Comment: Could you find a `postfix` option to attach a file? When I searched the docs I could not find one. Could you give it to me in a comment? As for only using one file: that will be possible. I will look into this tonight (CET).

Comment: @MarcusRickert 

for file in *.zip; do
mail -s object -a $file red@gmail.com;
done

this for me work fine

Comment: OK. If your `mail` binary can handle attachments all the better! I still assume that it is _not_ part of `postfix` but some other mail agent... It does not matter. For the enhanced version we'll be able to use it.

Comment: @MarcusRickert Ah, ok. how can find it? i have configured only POSTFIX.
QUEST:is possible in mailbody.txt put the variable $filename?
thx

Comment: @MarcusRickert Is possibile wait 10 seconds for sending email between their?
example: mail1 - 10sec - mail2 -10sec -ecc. ecc.

Comment: See my updated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can actually install `mutt` you can use the following script as a start:

```
#! /bin/bash

mail_body_file="mailbody.txt"
mail_address_file_extension=".txt"

for fullname in *.zip; do
    filename="${fullname%.*}"
    address_file=$filename$mail_address_file_extension
    if [ -f $address_file ] ; then
        echo "Address file found for ZIP $fullname"
        recipients=$(cat $address_file)
        echo "Sending mail to recipients $recipients..."      
        mutt -a $fullname -- -s "Attachment $fullname" "$recipients" < $mail_body_file
        sleep 10
        echo "Done."
    else
        echo "WARNING: no address file found for ZIP $fullname"
    fi
done
```

Notes:

- The mail client `mutt` will cleanly append the zip file as an attachment. @KyleBanerjee: This is not the same as just piping something into the mail!
- The mail client `mutt` should not interfere with the mail transport agent `postfix`. In fact, I assume that `mutt` will call the `sendmail` compatible interface of `postfix` to actually send the mail.
- The script currently assumes that everything is in the current directory.
- The script will fail if there isn't a single `.zip` file in the current directory.
- You will have to supply a file `mailbody.txt` to be used as the body of the mail.
- You may want to alter the subject (see parameter after `-s` to `mutt`).
- The address files must contain a semicolon seperated list of mail addresses, e.g.

  ```
   red@gmail.com;red1@gmail.com;red2@gmail.com
  ```

Comment: I'm using postfix together inotifywait...  POSTFIX is ok?

Comment: Yes, IMHO `mutt` does not collide with `postfix` it will _use_ `postfix`. Also see my extended notes above.

Comment: @pasaico: Do you need more help with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Much easier to just write a quick shell script:

```
for x in  `ls *.zip |sed "s/\.zip//"`

do
        mail $x@gmail.com < $x.zip
done
```

Comment: I also need to send them to different addresses...5,6 mail addresses

Comment: You could still use this basic method in conjunction with the "join" command. In the loop, dump the part of the filename up to .zip into a file, join that with a file with email addresses keyed with the name you provided, and you're good.

Is there a reason why simply enumerating the files and email addresses won't do since you obviously need some kind of table to describe who gets what?

Comment: @pasaico does not simply enumerate the email addresses. He uses a naming convention for his zip files and the associated mail address files. They only differ by their extensions.

Comment: If we don't know how many email addresses each gets sent to, how would we avoid some kind of table? If we do know how many (e.g., it's 5 or 6 or whatever), either they could be enumerated or another loop could set up to iterate through the addresses -- incrementing a variable and adding it to the name would be pretty easy.